# Why does my Axios Post Request not work with the Tor Browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, axios, tor

I am currently working on my React Website and Nodejs Server.
In my Project I have this simple piece of code:

```
Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/login", {
         username: username,
         password: password,
     }).then((response)  => {
         if(response.data.error){
             setErrorMsg(response.data.error);
         }else{
             setSuccesMsg(response.data.succes);
         }
     });
```

And it works perfect with my Chrome Browser.
Now i tried it with my Tor Browser and it does not make this Post Request to my Nodejs Server.
How can I fix it and is it normal because the ip is localhost.3001 ?

And is there a alternative for Axios where i can do post request to a onion site, because then i would host my Nodejs server as a hidden service and would make the post request to the onion link.

Thank you